# Je vais en goûter ou y goûter ?

Tags: usage, pronoms

Qu'est-ce qu'on dit quand quelqu'un vous propose de manger de la tarte ?

- Oui, je vais *en* goûter un peu;
- Oui, je vais *y* goûter un peu;
- Oui, je vais goûter un peu.

Answer (score 11):

Les deux phrases

> Oui, je vais en goûter un peu"

et

> Oui, je vais y goûter un peu

sont correctes.

Cependant, une meilleure tournure serait « Oui, j'aimerais y goûter », ou « Oui, j'en veux bien. »

En effet le verbe *aller* indique une action future que tu as décidée toi-même : que la personne le veuille ou non, tu **vas** manger de la tarte.

L'utilisation du verbe *aimer* ou *vouloir* permet de répondre à une proposition de façon polie et respectueuse.

Answer (score 3):

Lorsque quelqu'un vous propose de manger de la tarte en vous montrant cette tarte, on est dans le domaine du futur immédiat, qui exige une réponse du type “oui merci, avec plaisir” ou “non merci, je n'en veux pas” (ou “non merci, je suis repu”, pour rester poli).

Dans ce cas, “je vais y goûter” me paraît la formule la plus correcte, pour répondre à un étranger (hors famille proche). Préciser “un peu” est facultatif, dans la mesure où “goûter” quelque chose, c'est n'en prendre qu'un peu. Tout manger n'est plus goûter, et si vous le faites, on ne vous invitera plus, probablement.

“J'en veux bien” est une tournure plus conviviale, à réserver à la famille et aux amis. En revanche, “j'en veux bien” n'implique rien en terme de quantité, et si les autres sont déjà servis, et que la part restante ne vous fait pas peur, vous pouvez probablement finir la tarte sans risquer d'être jeté dehors.

J'aime moins “j'aimerais bien”, dont le conditionnel évoque l'hésitation de l'invité mal à l'aise. Une bonne maîtresse de maison y répondra en vous mettant d'office la plus grosse part de tarte entre les mains, une moins bonne en vous tournant le dos.

Answer (score 0):

Le verbe « gouter » a la particularité de vouloir dire trois choses  très rapprochées en sens.

D'abord il signifie « manger ou boire de quelque chose en très petite quantité pour savoir quel gout a ce que l'on mange ou ce que l'on boit ». Dans ce cas il est transitif direct.

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gouter)  P. méton. Manger ou boire quelque chose en petite quantité afin d'en vérifier la saveur et de l'apprécier à sa juste valeur.

Ensuite il signifie tout simplement « manger » ou «boire ». Il est alors transitif direct  et la préposition est « **à** ».

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gouter) I. Emploi trans. indir. A. Goûter à. Boire, manger une certaine quantité de.

Ceci contredit de façon flagrante [le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gouter) ;

> transitif indirect : Gouter à quelque chose ou quelqu'un
>
> Déguster une petite quantité d’un aliment afin d’en apprécier la saveur.
>           As-tu gouté aux abricots ?

Finalement il sert à dire « manger ou boire quelque chose pour la première fois » et dans ce dernier cas il est toujours transitif indirect mais la préposition est « **de** ».

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gouter) B. Goûter de
>   1. Manger ou boire pour la première fois. Goûter d'une boisson exotique, d'une orange amère.

Au vue de ces trois définitions et en s'en tenant au TLFi, si on considère la première phrase, dans laquelle est utilisé le pronom « **en** » il s'ensuit que l'on dit « Oui, je vais gouter **de** la tarte un peu . » ;  en fin de compte, ce que l'on dit vraiment c'est que l'on va manger de la tarte pour la première fois (troisième possibilité) et ce n'est pas ce que l'on a en tête.
Si on considère la seconde, dans laquelle on trouve le pronom « y », il s'ensuit que ce que l'on dit vraiment est « Oui, je vais manger de la tarte. » ;
Il se trouve donc que seulement la seconde des deux premières phrases convient.
La troisième, bien que incorrecte est celle qui exprimera la notion que presque toujours les gens ont en tête lorsqu'ils utilisent le verbe « gouter », c'est à dire prendre un tout petit peu de qqc pour vérifier le gout ; pour cela il suffit d'ajouter le complément d'objet direct (la) : « Oui, je vais la gouter. ».

On voit donc que cette forme verbale est très difficile à utiliser et que les gens se trompent souvent (les français eux-mêmes). Cela indique qu'il est préférable, tout au moins au début, lorsqu'on apprend, de n'utiliser le verbe « gouter » que pour le sens premier d'essayer quelque chose pour déterminer le gout et de se rabattre sur un verbe plus facile pour « boire » et « manger » (d'ailleurs, « gouter » selon les autres sens-là tend à être littéraire). De tels verbes sont les suivants : « prendre », « manger ». On peut aussi utiliser d'autres verbes qui implique cette idée : vouloir, faire plaisir, etc.

*déterminer le gout*

- J'ai gouté la sauce, elle est très bonne. (*et non « J'ai gouté à la sauce »*)
- Goutez cela et dites-moi ce que vous en pensez.

*consommer*

- Oui, je vais en prendre/manger un peu.  (prendre de qqc, manger de qqc)
- Oui, j'aimerais en manger/prendre un peu.
- Oui, je veux bien en manger/prendre un peu.