# Goûter un peu : pléonasme ou pas ?

Tags: humour

La question sur le fait de “goûter un peu” a fait tilt en moi, dans la mesure où “goûter”, c'est forcément un peu. J'ai été élevé dans cette idée, mais comme je me retrouvais toujours à laver la vaisselle aux repas anniversaires, je ne suis pas sûr d'avoir raison.

C'est l'éternelle histoire de “descendre en bas” et de “monter en haut”, pléonasmes bien connus.

Et pourtant, on peut “monter en bas” (ou en collants, plus chauds en hiver), et “descendre en haut” (de chausse, la chaussette du Moyen-Âge, qui connaissait déjà l'escalier) sans heurter l'érudit.

Donc “descendre en bas” et “monter en haut” usurpent peut-être parfois leur réputation de pléonasmes.

Alors, “goûter un peu” : pléonasme ou pas ?

Comment: En fonction du contexte, monter en haut et descendre en bas sont tout à fait des pléonasmes; Ils sont certainement souvent utilisés en tant que tel d'ailleurs car les exemples donnés sont quand-même très spécifiques.

Comment: En fait, mon intention était juste de montrer (avec le sourire) que la langue française peut être parfois un peu déroutante, avec quelques exemples concrets pour expliquer ce qu'est un pléonasme. Et demander l'avis des autres : peut-on “goûter beaucoup” (une tarte, dans le sujet d'origine), auquel cas “goûter un peu” n'est PAS un pléonasme. Parce qu'il me semble avoir déjà entendu “je goûte beaucoup” cet évènement, ce concert, ce match de foot … où le fait de goûter beaucoup ne réduit pas la part des autres. :^)

Answer (score 3):

En fonction du contexte, monter en haut et descendre en bas sont tout à fait des pléonasmes; Ils sont certainement souvent utilisés en tant que tel d'ailleurs car les exemples donnés sont quand-même très spécifiques.

Il en est selon moi de même pour [Goûter](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/go%C3%BBter) :

L'une des définitions est "Manger ou boire quelque chose en petite quantité afin d'en vérifier la saveur et de l'apprécier à sa juste valeur". Dans ce cas en effet, *goûter un peu* me semble être un pléonasme car par définition on ne va pas en manger une plâtrée.

Les autres définitions peuvent selon moi s’accommoder de telles nuances (un peu, beaucoup,...) sans être des pléonasmes.

Answer (score 2):

*Goûter* suivi d'une locution adverbiale ce n'est pas toujours un pléonasme car cette dernière permet de préciser la quantité que l'on souhaite prélever :

> Goûter **un peu**

c'est goûter suffisamment mais sans excès, alors que :

> goûter **un tout petit peu**

indique que le prélèvement sera très réduit, au risque de ne pas pleinement percevoir la saveur du produit, au contraire de :

> goûter **un gros morceau de**...

où le prélèvement pourra être exagéré.

Si je dis à ma fille :

> Je peux goûter ta glace ?

elle me répondra peut-être

> Oui, mais juste **un peu** !

***Goûter beaucoup***, c'est aussi goûter plusieurs produits distincts :

> [Pour connaître globalement les particularités d’un millésime, c’est toujours pareil, il faut **goûter beaucoup** et observer les similitudes.](http://www.labivin.net/article-25785582.html)

D'ailleurs, beaucoup de pléonasmes ont un rôle utile dans le discours. Celui de renforcer un message est bien connu. La redondance peut aussi clarifier ce qui est dit et donc faciliter la compréhension. Certaines expressions que l'on retrouve toujours quand on aborde le sujet des pléonasmes mériteraient un effort de réhabilitation. On ne monte pas toujours en haut et on ne descend pas toujours en bas.

*Monter **vers** le haut* est un pléonasme mais *monter **en haut*** indique une destination (plus ou moins précise suivant le contexte), ce que *monter* tout seul ne fait pas, p. ex. :

> Tu comptes monter en haut ?
>   Non, je m'arrête au camp de base.

La fréquence de monter en haut et descendre en bas dans le français parlé montre que la locution a un rôle.

Même le doublement pléonastique *au jour d'aujourd'hui* insiste sur le fait qu'on parle bien de l'aujourd'hui d'aujourd'hui, et pas d'un aujourd'hui plus large, plus flou où *aujourd'hui* signifie simplement *de nos jours*.

Comment: Le dernier exemple résulte d'un truchement par le passage de « gouter qqc » à « manger de qqc » dans l'esprit de l'interlocuteur ; ce n(est pas valable.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Il est communément admis que *monter en haut* est un pléonasme mais je considère que c'est partiellement exagéré. *Monter **vers** le haut* est un pléonasme mais *monter **en haut*** indique une destination (plus ou moins précise suivant le contexte), ce que *monter* tout seul ne fait pas, ex : *Tu comptes monter en haut ? Non, je m'arrête au camp de base.* La fréquence de cette formule dans le français parlé montre qu'elle joue un rôle. D'autre part, que la définition de *goûter* ne précise pas la quantité me renforce dans l'idée qu'ajouter cette information peut être pertinent.

Comment: Parfaitement d'accord avec cette réponse, et avec votre opinion que la réputation pléonasmique de *«monter en haut»* est surfaite. Je dis communément monter en haut pour mon habitation, qui a deux étage (un seul en France). Je suppose que nous pourrions utiliser *«monter au haut»*, mais ce n'est ni élégant ni commun. Quand je monte en haut, je ne vais pas sur le toît ou le dessus de la cheminée, ni même au grenier. Je me rends au deuxième (à l'étage en France). N’en déplaise à mes anciens profs...

Answer (score 0):

> Pléonasme : *Didact.* Terme ou expression qui ne fait qu'ajouter une répétition à ce qui vient d'être énoncé.

Le verbe « goûter » à plusieurs définitions.

> Goûter : **v. tr.** *Spécialt.* (plus cour.) Manger ou boire une petite quantité de (qqch.), afin d'en éprouver la saveur.

[Dans le sujet mentionné](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/38177/19460), l'expression « goûter un peu » est un pléonasme.

Answer (score -1):

La question qui se pose n'est pas celle de savoir si un pléonasme résulte ; après réflexion on la situe comme étant celle de savoir si « un peu » est un concept compatible avec celui de « gouter » ; il ne l'est pas essentiellement parce que « gouter » est essentiellement un verbe perfectif et que les quantificateurs (« peu » est un quantificateur de l'intensité faible ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peu)) ne sont pas compatibles avec ces verbes. Prenons par exemple les verbes perfectifs « trouver », « sortir », « naître », « atteindre »,  « mourir ». Est-ce que cela a du sens de dire ou écrire des choses telles que les suivantes ?

- Il est né un peu le 18 avril 1930.
- Il meurt un peu.
- Il a  atteint le but un peu.
- Il avait perdu sa montre mais hier il l'a trouvée un peu.

On le voit assez clairement en utilisant des verbes perfectifs dont la caractéristique est bien marquée ; les quantificateurs ne sont as compatibles avec ces verbes. C'est donc le point de sémantique concerné et non celui du pléonasme. Cependant, le verbe « gouter » n'est apparemment pas parfaitement perfectif.
Il est possible que dans certaines situations il ne soit pas si illogique de dire « gouter un peu », que l'emploi du quantificateur ait une certaine justification. Par exemple dans le cas d'un vin fin le processus de le gouter n'est pas limité à son effet sur le palais et après avoir humé le bouquet d'un tel liquide on pourrait être en droit lorsqu'on nous demande si on l'a gouté,  de répondre « Oui, un peu, j'ai pu me rendre compte du bouquet. ».
  Évidemment, utiliser « un peu » dans le sens spécial suivant change tout;

> [TLFi, **II A 4**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peu) Verbe + un peu.  [En fonction d'adv. de phrase] Pop. et fam.
>   − [Empl. seul, comme réponse en forme de défi] Plutôt. [Sert à mettre au défi, mais gén. par jeu, à menacer, mais sans réelle gravité]

Dire alors quelque chose comme « Goutes un peu ! » ne soulève plus de doutes, mais on n'est plus dans le domaine de la question.

Comment: J'ai publié cet article humoristique pour dire que “goûter” suffit, et que le “un peu” est implicite. Mais comme je n'ai pas la science infuse, je demande l'opinion des autres. Avec quelques exemples concrets pour expliquer de façon simple ce qu'est un pléonasme.

Parce que je pense que les personnes qui posent des questions dans la communauté “French Language” ne sont pas forcément des “French natives”, et que pour eux, un bon exemple vaut mieux qu'un long discours.

PS : J'ai essayé de vous noter “-1”, mais je n'ai pas suffisamment de réputations pour le faire.

Comment: @dralpuop Je ne vois pas trop où vous voulez en venir, si ce n'est que vous réfutez l'argumentation sans la considérer ;  vous ne faites aucun effort pour comprendre et devez penser que nécessairement toute explication est à votre portée et qu'il n'y a rien que vous ne puissiez comprendre ; c'est nécessairement la faute de celui qui explique. C'est assez bizarre et de la part de quelqu'un qui serait assez logique pour suspecter un pléonasme. Ma conviction  est que l'addition de « un peu » est en gros une erreur **et**  cette erreur **ne s'appelle pas un pléonasme** . (champ 1/2)

Comment: @dralpuop Je dois aussi préciser que s'il n'est pas interdit de mêler son humour et celui des autres à une question, cet article humoristique **est une question** et c'est pour cette raison que 2 réponses y correspondent. Vous ne saviez vraiment pas, vous avez publié pour acquérir des certitudes qui vous manquaient. (champ 2/2)

Comment: TLFi = ‘Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé’. Je ne connaissais pas le terme, je l'ai cherché sur Internet. Composé de 16 tomes dont le dernier a été publié en 1994 (soit 4 ans après la réforme de la langue française), le TLFi n'a pas vocation a être actualisé, m'informe-t-on. (Précision pour la suite).

Comment: @dralpuop N'hésitez pas à poser des questions, les commentaires sont là pour ça et les utilisateurs du site se feront un plaisir de vous donner l'information qui vous manque, s'il le peuvent, bien sûr.

Comment: “La question qui se pose n'est pas celle de savoir si un pléonasme résulte” : sur quelle planète vivez-vous ? Votre réponse est incompréhensible au néophyte, en particulier la personne qui posait la question “Je vais en goûter ou y goûter ?”, et qui n'est probablement un “French Native”. Brisons là, voulez-vous ? Avant de nous fâcher …

Comment: *Partir, c'est mourir un peu*...

Comment: @jlliagre Cela n'a absolument rien à voir avec la langue factuelle ; c'est de la langue imagée qui n'a pas sa place dans le présent contexte. personne ne répondra jamais à la la question « Est-ce que tu l'as gouté ? » par « Oui,  un peu. ».

Comment: @Fólkvangr C'est trop compliqué quand cela vous arrange de le trouver compliqué ; c'est seulement que vous ne comprenez pas et en fait ce n'est pas si compliqué, c'est de la sémantique et on trouve toutes sortes d'incompatibilité dans ce genre en sémantique ; c'est de la linguistique et c'est seulement vrai ou pas vrai ; je crois que c'est vrai : il n'y a qu'à considérer les exemples simples que j'ai fournis pour découvrir le schéma absurde ; tous les verbes sont des verbes perfectifs. (On s'occupe encore (un peu) de sémantique en français sur le FSE.)

Comment: @Fólkvangr D'abord, l'aspect. Je *ne crois pas* que ce soit un verbe **im**perfectif ; la définition [suivante](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_perfectif/imperfectif) montre cela ; je la répète : « L’aspect perfectif indique un procès qui ne peut être réalisé qu'une fois parvenu à son terme ». « gouter » n'est réalisé que lorsque le processus « porter de la nourriture à la bouche - commencer à mâcher - mâcher  un instant - avaler » est terminé ; si on crache la nourriture après avoir commencé à mâcher (elle est trop chaude par exemple) le processus n'est pas parvenu à son terme.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Le rapport entre le quantitatif et le verbal se décèle dans la nature de l'action exprimée; c'est un rapport purement sémantique; certaines actions sont passibles d'une qualification quantitative (d'une sorte donnée ou de plusieurs), d'autre non ; cela dépend du sens du verbe ; une même forme verbale peut, selon son sens, être passible d'une telle qualification ou non. Par exemple, dans « Il voit l'avion atterrir.» on n'ajoute jamais « beaucoup », « un peu », « plus » ; cependant, dans « Il voit ses enfants. » il n'y a pas de problème.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Le procès est imperfectif parce que dès qu'il est commencé il est pleinement réalisé ; l'ampoule peut s'arrêter de luire à tout moment mais pendant le temps qui précède ce moment elle aura bien lui tout le temps.